# Conda: Command not found

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm a 17-year-old, and I am new to programming. I installed anaconda and python on my laptop however every time that I run code in Sublime Text it gives this error before printing whatever I want it to print: 
/Users/eyan/.bash_profile: line 20: conda: command not found
It's really annoying so is there a way to get rid of it.

Comment: How long since you installed anaconda? Have you closed and reopened your terminal or ran `EXEC $SHELL` in the terminal since installing?

Comment: I'm guessing your conda installation is not on your windows path. Either (1) you uninstall and reinstall your anaconda completely, or, (2) you find your anaconda installation and place it in your windows PATH [link](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/).

Comment: @NicholasTJ I'm working on Mac Catalina

Comment: @OllieinPGH Yes I'm closed and reopened and it's still there. Also I dont know how to run EXEC $SHELL because it's giving me an error when I run it. Sorry I'm a beginner and don't know how to do these things yet

Answer (score 6):

The difference between bash and zshell are minimal. They are both a "shell" that run in the terminal. A shell is what allows you to run commands in the terminal. It has its own language called `bash` or alternatively `shell scripting`. If you have ever typed `ls` or `cd` in a terminal, you are using bash commands to move around or look at things in the terminal. (The terminal itself is just the little oftentimes black square you type into.) It doesn't really matter which one you pick at this point, but you should just go with one.

If you pick bash, the files that interact with it will be under your home directory, the error tells you exactly where. `/Users/eyan/.bash_profile` the `.bash_profile` sets some configurations for bash.

If you pick zshell, the files will instead of starting with `'.bash_` they'll start with `.zsh` the most common one will be `.zshrc` and it will be in the same home directory. So `/Users/eyan/.zshrc` will be the config file for zshell.

Pick one and just stay with it for now.

In either case, you want to initialize conda.

In your terminal, if you type:

`which conda`

It should tell you where your conda is installed. If you get a bunch of nonsense running that, try `which python`. One of them should give you something like this output:

`/Users/eyan/opt/anaconda3/bin/python`

Change the `python` in that line to `activate` and add the command `source` to the front. So type:

`source /Users/eyan/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate`

Once you've done that type:

`conda init`

All of this is done in the terminal. And that should add a bunch of stuff to your shell profiles. (That's those files in your home directory like `.bash` and `.zshrc`.)

If you close and reopen your terminal or type `EXEC $SHELL` in the same terminal window, you should be able to use conda.

You can also see what was added to your bash (or zsh) profiles by typing:

`cat /Users/eyan/.bash_profile`

(Or if you've chosen zshell, run `cat /Users/eyan/.zshrc`)

You'll see that conda added quite a few lines to it. Don't worry about what those lines do for now, but you can see them there.

Answer (score 2):

That means that your shell doesn't know where to find `conda` binary. In order for him to know where to look for it you should run:

```
/absolute/path/to/anaconda3/folder/bin/conda init
source ~/.bash_profile
```

usually the default path should be `~/anaconda3` and therefore you should be good with

```
~/anaconda3/bin/conda init
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: I'm using a mac catalina and I'm also a bit confused between what bash and zsh are and which one I should use. Whenever I go terminal preferences shells open with command (complete path) and make it /bin/bash it gives this error when I open the terminal  : -bash: conda: command not found
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.                                But whenever I use /bin/zsh it doesn't give that error on terminal only on sublime text

Comment: I tried both the inputs you wrote and they said this:                                                             -bash: /absolute/path/to/anaconda3/folder/bin/conda: No such file or directory

Comment: I tried those two and it gave me:                                                                                       zsh: no such file or directory: /Users/eyan/anaconda3/bin/conda

Comment: If you used a graphical installer try: `~/opt/anaconda3/bin/conda init` and then `source .bash_profile`